# Is it appropriate to ask questions concerning proof assistance software on this site?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Is it appropriate to ask questions about executing mathematical proofs in proof assistance tools, such as Coq, on this site?

Comment: I don't see a problem with this (though I have no idea how many users who know Coq).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. And please tag the question with the [theorem-provers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theorem-provers) tag.

Comment: Thanks! I will make sure to do as you say.